# Use a resource ( progressbar ) in multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

So most of my layouts have the same base structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/upperLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:elevation="17dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mainLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
            //CONTENT
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am using those progressbars by changing their visibility in Java whenever I make a request.
How can I define upperLoading and mainLoading and then reuse them in multiple layouts? I am new to android so I am sorry if this question is too simple.

Comment: if you want to use this layout multiple times. then there is an attribute in xml

 <include layout="@layout/yourlayout"/> using that you can have this same layout in multiple activities xml files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new layout with the reusable views and use the `<include />` tag to add to another `layout.xml`

See here for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

I imagine various aproaches to solve your issue, but I believe putting your progress bar inside a new layout file and then reusing it with the  tag is the best and simplest way.

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) says:

> Inside the layout to which you want to add the re-usable component,
>   add the  tag.

So, in your case, I would do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/upperLoading_progressbar_layout"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
      xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

      ...

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<FrameLayou>
```

And according to this example, you will need to create a new xml file called upperLoading_progressbar_layout where you'll put your reusable progress bar.

Comment: Thank you this solution helps as well, but @RED_ 's solution came first. Thank  you for your time!